# How is $\Phi$ used in the definition of a $S$-definition of $P$ in $\Phi$?

Tags: logic, definition, computer-science, model-theory

On [p126](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false)   in *§3.  Extensions by Definitions* in *VIII  Syntactic Interpretations and  Normal Forms* In Ebbinghaus' *Mathematical Logic*: $S$ is a (non-logical) symbol set

> 3.1  Definition.  Let $\Phi$  be a set of $S$-sentences.
>
> (a)  Suppose  $P \notin S$ is  an $n$-ary relation symbol and $\phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})$  an
> $S$-formula. Then we say that
> $$ \forall v_0, .... \forall v_{n-1}   (P v_0 ... n_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})) $$
> is  an $S$-definition of $P$  in $\Phi$.

How is $\Phi$ used in the definition of a $S$-definition of $P$ in $\Phi$?

- $\Phi$  is a set of $S$-sentences,
- $\phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})$ is a $S$-formula, but not a $S$-sentence, so not in $\Phi$,
- $P \notin S$, so  $ P v_0 ... n_{n-1} $ and $ \forall v_0, .... \forall v_{n-1}   (P v_0 ... n_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})) $ are $S'$-sentences not  $S$-sentences, so not in $\Phi$.

Thanks.

Comment: Not needed in 3.1(a), but necessary for (b) and (c).

Answer (score 1):

What Definition 3.1(a) wants to convey is the following: say that you start with an axiom system $\Phi$ and you want have a way of "picking-up" $n$-tuples of elements in models $M$ of $\Phi$ which belong to a subset of $M^n$ satisfying some first order property given by an $S$-formula $\varphi_P(v_0, \dots, v_{n-1})$. To do so, one introduces a new $n$-ary relation symbol $P$ and extends the axiom system $\Phi$ to a new axiom system $\Phi \cup \{\delta_P\}$ in the new symbol set $S' = S \cup \{P\}$, where $$\delta_P := \forall v_0, .... \forall v_{n-1}   (P v_0 ... n_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \varphi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1}));$$
the $S'$-sentence $\delta_P$ fixes the interpretation of the new symbol $P$ in models of $\Phi \cup \{\delta_p\}$. Now, the Theorem on Definitions (3.2) ensures us that we're not doing anything silly (namely, that both $\Phi$ and $\Phi \cup \{\delta_P\}$ prove the same theorems, so $\Phi \cup \{\delta_P\}$ is a *conservative extension* of $\Phi$) and that we really didn't had to add any new symbol to $S$ in order to pick-up those $n$-tuples of elements (i.e. $\varphi_P$ plays exactly the same role in models of $\Phi$ as $P$ does in models of $\Phi \cup \{\delta_P\}$).

The point is that to extend the symbol set $S$ by a new relation symbol $P$, there is no further condition which our axiom system $\Phi$ needs to satisfy, and that is why it seems as if $\Phi$ is not used in the definition of an $S$-definition for $P$. This is not however the case for the extension by definitions for constant symbols and function symbols. For the case of constant symbols one needs to ensure that the $S$-formula $\varphi_c$ defining the new constant symbol $c$ *uniquely determines* the interpretation of $c$ in models of $\Phi$, i.e. we need to impose the condition that $\Phi \models \exists^{=1}v_0\varphi_c(v_0)$. Definition 3.1(b) for the $S$-definition of a function symbol follows a similar idea.

Comment: Thanks. Your way of using the word "axioms" reminded me of whether the axioms in any first order logic system belong to two different levels. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773295/does-axiom-in-the-axioms-of-group-theory-mean-the-same-as-axiom-in-first-o